# Was Project X based on a real incident or vice versa?

Tags: production, project-x

Was the movie Project X based on events of a real incident or did parties get thrown to mimic Project X?

Was there a real party (thrown by a teenager) that lead to a riot and news coverage that lead to the making of this film? Or were the real world parties of a similar nature leading to a riot a consequence of the movie?

Comment: ... Or maybe I misunderstand even more... the Wikipedia article seems to answer your question ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_X_%282012_film%29#Impact

Comment: @catija, the article talks about impacts. But doesn't say anything about actual parties that may have happened before the film.

Answer (score 2):

It was based on an amalgamation of real events and incidents, primarily though the filmmakers referenced this one...